# The method is not allowed for the requested URL. flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, python-2.7, flask

I try to make a web service that is to the login of a user. I want the web pages are dynamic, so I work with javascript jquery html and the problem if I filled username and password in the correct values then passing to another

127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2015 08:54:42] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2015 08:54:51] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 405 -

this /loginuser

```html
@APP.route('/loginuser', methods=['POST'])
def login():

    error = None
    con = mdb.connect('localhost','testuser', 'test623', 'test') 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ADMIN")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    login=False
    for row in rows:
             if request.form['username'] == row[0] and  request.form['password'] == row[1]:
                login=True
                print request.form['username']
                print request.form['password']
           
    
    if login ==False:
             error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
             response.result == error
    else:
             
             response.result == "success"
    con.close
```

and this /login

```html
@APP.route('/login')
def login1():

      return render_template('login1.html')
```

script.js

```js
function loginAndRedirect (){
 var user = $('#txtUsername').val();
 var pass = $('#txtPassword').val();
 $.ajax({
  url: '/loginuser',
  data: $('form').serialize(),
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response){

   if (response.result == "success") {
    alert("You have been logged in!");
    window.location.href="hello.html";
   } else {
    alert(result.details);          
   }
  },
  error: function(error){
   console.log(error);
  }
 }); 
}
```

and login:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MONOTORING_LAN</title>
<link href="static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="static/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <section id="content">
  <form method="POST" class="form-signin" role="form">
   <h1>Login Form</h1>
   <div> 
                             
    <input type="text" id="txtUsername" placeholder="Username" name="username"  required autofocus>
                                <input type="password" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password" required autofocus>
                               <input class="btn btn-default" id = "submitButton" type="submit" value="Login">
  
                      </div>
  </form><!-- form -->
  {% if error %}
                    <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
                {% endif %}
 </section><!-- content -->

</div><!-- container -->
</body>
 <script src="static/js/script.js>
      $(".form-signin").on("submit", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        loginAndRedirect();});
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the `/loginuser` and `/login` handlers and how you are invoking them that results in the exception?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you never actually hook your script up to the `form`'s `submit` event, and so the form is submitted by the browser.  However, since you don't specify an `action` attribute, so the form submits itself to the URL it's currently on (`/login`) resulting in the 405 you are seeing now.  Hook up your `loginAndRedirect` to the form's `submit` event, and you will no longer POST to the `/login` endpoint:

```
<script>
$(".form-signin").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  loginAndRedirect();
});
</script>
```

Some tips:

- Add an `action` pointing at the `/loginAndRedirect` endpoint so even if your JavaScript fails the user can still log in (unless you are planning on building a Single-Page App)
- Rather than looking up all of the users and walking through them in the application, add a `WHERE` clause to your SQL lookup and look the user up by `username` and `password`.  Don't concatenate the user-provided values with your SQL, but instead use a parameterized query.
- You need to return a response, not assign to the `response` object (Flask doesn't provide one, so it's something local to your project).

Comment: thank you sir I am sorry for the inconvenience, I am a beginner in jquery, could you still explain more the script or I have to put in the html page right? and for the points you have me speak especially the last item I did not quite understand  @Sean Vieira

Comment: Yes, put the script just before the `</body>` tag and it will work. As for the need for `return` in your Flask method for `/loginAndRedirect` - Flask will throw an error if you don't `return some_response` to the client.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems seen by me in your `login()` function:

1. you don't return the `response` object, and where did you get it from anyway?
2. `con.close` should be `con.close()`, but I supose you should close cursor too:

   ```
   cur.close()
   con.close()
   ```

Comment: For response I will use in script.js for return the page hello.htm              if (response.result == "success") {
    alert("You have been logged in!");
    window.location.href="hello.html";
   } else {
    alert(result.details);          
   }

Comment: I change like you said but the same result :( The method is not allowed for the requested URL.